# Sheets Filter Script across multiple tabs displaying blank rows on master sheet, and also causing other scripts to stop functioning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a multifaceted question.

I'm attempting to have a script which pulls the tab names, and uses that info to pull specific cells from each one (tabs for the doc change frequently) in order to create a Master Sheet. The Master Sheet is meant to display all open action items, and filter out any closed items / blank rows. The script I have so far works, but it pulls all empty rows from each tab - which I don't want.

Here's 1 of the 2 current scripts I have for the master sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  //set variable
  const masterSheet = "Open Action Items";
  const mastersheetFormulaCell = "E2";
  const ignoreSheets = ["Template", "Blank"];
  const dataRange = "I2:K";
  const checkRange = "J2:J"
  //end set variables

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ignoreSheets.push(masterSheet);

  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();

  const filteredListOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

  let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `iferror(FILTER('${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange}, NOT(ISBLANK('${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRange}))),{"","",""})`);

  let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";
 
  ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(mastersheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaText);

}
```

The other part of this is another script that has been running ok when it was the only script running, but has since stopped working when the other script were introduced. This script added a checkbox to column C based on criteria in column B.

Here's that script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (e.value === "Tech Note" || 
        e.value === "Intake Process")
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).insertCheckboxes();
    else
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).removeCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

**[Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Jd6Zm4VsxHAsRW29Dbm_0Nsmb0RjtP_8kmsl_1k0Kw/edit?usp=sharing)**

The "Open Action Items" tab is the master sheet the script is meant to update. It should list all the open items from other tabs (explained below)
The "Copy of E3-O Case Notes" is a tab which is the basis of what every tab will eventually look like. Columns F-K of this tab pull open items from A-E. There may likely be a more efficient way to sort this whole sheet...

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address the second question first, as it's a more fundamental problem.

> The other part of this is another script that has been running ok when it was the only script running, but has since stopped working when the other script were introduced.

In the script project attached to your sample, you have 3 files which each define an `onEdit()` function. This is problematic because each time you define `onEdit()` you're redefining the same identifier. **The project only has a single global scope, so there can only be 1 `onEdit()` function defined, regardless of how many files your project contains**.

Essentially, this is equivalent to what you've defined in your project:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log("onEdit #1");
}

function onEdit(e) {
  console.log("onEdit #2");
}

function onEdit(e) {
  console.log("onEdit #3");
}

onEdit();
```

Running the above snippet will only execute the last definition of `onEdit()`.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you can instead define unique functions for all the actions you want to perform and then, in a single `onEdit()` definition, you can call those functions. Something like:

```js
function editAction1(e) {
  console.log("edit action #1");
}

function editAction2(e) {
  console.log("edit action #2");
}

function editAction3(e) {
  console.log("edit action #3");
}

function onEdit(e) {
  editAction1(e);
  editAction2(e);
  editAction3(e);
}

onEdit();
```

---

When defining an `onEdit()` trigger, you really want to optimize it so that it can complete its execution as quickly as possible. From the Apps Script best practices, you want to pay particular attention to ["Minimize calls to other services"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services) and ["Use batch operations"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

A few specific tips for you:

- Avoid repeated calls to the same Apps Script API (e.g. `Sheet.getName()`). Instead, run it once and store the value in local variable.
- As much as possible, avoid making Apps Script API calls within loops and in callback functions passed to methods such as `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.map()`.
- When you do need to loop through data, especially when Apps Script API calls are involved, minimize the number of times you iterate through the data.
- With `onEdit()` triggers, try to structure the logic so that you identify cases where you can exit early (similar to how you perform the column check before going ahead with manipulating checkboxes). I doubt you actually need to iterate through all of the sheets and update the "Open Action Items" formula for every single edit. If I'm interpreting the formula properly, it's something that should only be done when sheets are added or removed.

---

Finally, to address the blank rows in your formula output, instead of using `SORT()` to group the blank rows you can use `QUERY()` to actually filter them out.

Something like:

```
=QUERY({ <...array contents...> }, "select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Note that when using `QUERY()` you need to be careful that the input data is consistent in regards to type. From [the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) (emphasis mine):

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
> determines the data type of the column for query purposes. **Minority
> data types are considered null values**.

In your sample sheet, a lot of the example data varies and doesn't match what you'd actually expect to see (e.g. "dghdgh" as a value in a column meant for dates). This is important given the warning above... when you have mixed data types for a given column (i.e. numbers and strings) whichever type is least prevalent will silently be considered null.

After taking a closer, end-to-end look at your sample, I noticed you're performing a very convoluted series of transformations (e.g. in the data sheets there's the hidden "D" column, the `QUERY()` columns to the right of the actual data, etc.). This all culminates in a large set of parallel `QUERY()` calls that you're generating via your `onEdit()` implementation.

This can all be made so much simpler. Here's a pass at simplifying the Apps Script code, which is dependent on also cleaning up the spreadsheet that it's attached to.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  /*
  Both onEdit actions are specific to a subset of the sheets. This
  regular expression is passed to both functions to facilitate only
  dealing with the desired sheets.
  */
  const validSheetPattern = /^E[0-9]+/;
  
  updateCheckboxes(e, validSheetPattern);
  updateActionItems(e, validSheetPattern);
}

function updateCheckboxes(e, validSheetPattern) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  // Return immediately if the checkbox manipulation is unnecessary.
  if (!validSheetPattern.exec(sheet.getName())) return;
  if (e.range.getColumn() != 2) return;

  const needsCheckbox = ["Tech Note", "Intake Process"];
  const checkboxCell = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 3);
  if (needsCheckbox.includes(e.value)) {
      checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
  } else {
      checkboxCell.removeCheckboxes();
  }
}

function updateActionItems(e, validSheetPattern) { 
  const masterSheetName = "Open Action Items";
  const dataLocation = "A3:E";

  /*
  Track the data you need for generating formauls in an array
  of objects. Adding new formulas should be as simple as adding
  another object here, as opposed to duplicating the logic
  below with a growing set of manually indexed variable names
  (e.g. cell1/cell2/cell3, range1/range2/range3, etc.).
  */
  const formulas = [
    {
      location: "A3",
      code: "Tech Note",
    },
    {
      location: "E3",
      code: "Intake Process",
    },
  ];
  
  const masterSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(masterSheetName);
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  
  /*
  Instead of building an array of QUERY() calls, build an array of data ranges that
  can be used in a single QUERY() call.
  */
  let dataRangeParts = [];
  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    // Only call getSheetName() once, instead of multiple times throughout the loop.
    const name = sheet.getSheetName();

    // Skip this iteration of the loop if we're not dealing with a data sheet.
    if (!validSheetPattern.exec(name)) continue;

    dataRangeParts.push(`'${name}'!${dataLocation}`);
  }
  const dataRange = dataRangeParts.join(";");
    
  for (const formula of formulas) {
    /*
    And instead of doing a bunch of intermediate transformations within the sheet,
    just query the data directly in this generated query.
    */
    const query = `SELECT Col5,Col1,Col4 WHERE Col2='${formula.code}' AND Col3=FALSE`;
    const formulaText = `IFERROR(QUERY({${dataRange}},"${query}"),{"","",""})`;
    
    formula.cell = masterSheet.getRange(formula.location);
    formula.cell.setFormula(formulaText);
  }
}
```

Here's [a modified sample spreadsheet that you can reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nNf0w8W8fQU5W6yMzN-KJ1wMj_NQbH4Wyq3Kg8txoc/edit?usp=sharing).

The one concession I made is that the data sheets still have a "Site Code" column, which is automatically populated via a formula. Having all the data in the range(s) you feed into `QUERY()` makes the overall formulas for the "Open Action Items" sheet much simpler.

Comment: This was helpful, much appreciated!
I've updated the script, combining 2 of them into one, and making only 1 of them onedit(e).

I'm not sure I did everything you brought up correctly, but it does seem to be functioning as intended, now.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   :P
Lmk if I missed other pieces, or any other advice you have. Thank you!!

Comment: Updated the answer with an approach for filtering out the blank rows.

Comment: Thank you for all of this! I didn't realize an entire rewrite would be better, and I'm not as familiar with the methods you used, so it's been tough trying to navigate updating the script to fit the actual sheet. For example, the tabs this script should apply to won't always fit the "E#" format. I updated it so it would return a higher number than 9 (because there can be up to 100 tabs), but some include more than just E and a number. There are also additional tabs I need it to skip, other than just the master sheet. I know how to do this with other forms of code, but not this. :/

Comment: Oh, also! The reason I didn't initially use Query, is because the site codes need to retain their hyperlink. Is there a work-around, there?

Comment: The regular expression `/^E[0-9]+/` means a string that starts with `E` and is followed by 1 more occurrences of the characters `[0-9]`. Here's [an interactive example](https://regexr.com/5lfsq). For reference see [the MDN Regular Expression documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The important takeaway is to use a fail-close approach (i.e. explicitly identify the sheets to include, instead of the sheets to exclude).

Comment: Updated the modified sample sheet to demonstrate placing the query results in an intermediate sheet, adding a sheet with a simple mapping of site codes to URLs and then using a few formulas to build the final "Open Action Items" sheet by combining the query results with the mapping data.

Comment: Ok cool, much appreciated - I do have a script that automatically pulls sheet names and links which could be added, but not entirely sure how it would be combined into the current script - as I'd think trying to stack the script would lead to the same issue I started with. Sheets are added very regularly to this doc.