# Query & Timestamp Combined Script Not Working - Debug doesn't show issue(?)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to run a script that combines adding a timestamp upon edit to individual sheets, and also to place a query to create a master sheet of info from all sheets - both upon edit.

Here's the script I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const masterSheet = "1-Cover Sheet";
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const name = sheet.getName();
  const currentDate = new Date();
  
  editTimestamp(e, range);
  updateMasterSheetRows(e, masterSheet);
}

function editTimestamp(e, range) {

  var startRow = 1;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col === 7 && row === 3 && sheet.getRange(1,14).getValue() == "" && 
     sheet.getName() != "4-Transfer Walkthru" 
         sheet.getRange(1,14).setValue(currentDate);
       }
  
  else if(row >= startRow && 
     sheet.getName() != "4-Transfer Walkthru" && 
     sheet.getName() != "1-Cover Sheet"
    
    sheet.getRange(2,14).setValue(currentDate);
         }  
  }


function updateMasterSheetRows(e, masterSheet) { 
  const masterSheetName = "1-Cover Sheet";
  const dataLocation = "B224:U225";

  
  const formulas = [
    {
      location: "B4",
      code: "is not null",
    },
    ];
  

  const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  
  
  let dataRangeParts = [];
  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    
    const name = sheet.getSheetName();

    if (!masterSheet.exec(name)) continue;

    dataRangeParts.push(`'${name}'!${dataLocation}`);
  }
  const dataRange = dataRangeParts.join(";");
    
  for (const formula of formulas) {

    const query = `SELECT * WHERE Col1'${formula.code}'`;
    const formulaText = `IFERROR(QUERY({${dataRange}},"${query}"),{"","",""})`;
    
    formula.cell = masterSheet.getRange(formula.location);
    formula.cell.setFormula(formulaText);
  }
}
```

I've tried moving things around, but haven't been able to locate where the issue is.

[Here's a sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4cPIqLckUU9y1Zssh7L3AxxOYTsOhrJtHC-XkFfR3Q/edit?usp=sharing)

The sheets frequently change, with more being added. I'm looking to lessen the amount of formulas / loading time with this, so any ideas/help welcome!

Comment: simple triggered functions must complete within 30 seconds.

Comment: Not sure why I got down votes, or if there is an alternative suggested to fix this. 

I was told in another post to combine scripts to avoid multiple onEdit functions, so I assume splitting them up is not what should happen. Is there another trigger to use instead? Any help on what to do appreciated.

Comment: I’m not saying you should split them up I’m just saying that simple triggers can only trigger functions that last about 30 seconds so there are somethings you simply can’t do simple triggers and I think you’re probably trying to do too much so you’ll have to do that with a function that you tired to a menu or to a button click

Comment: Hi ! Please provide editor level access to the sample document you shared so that we can take a look and try to find out what you are trying to accomplish. Have you tried converting your function ```onEdit()``` into an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) rather than using it as a simple trigger ?

Comment: Whoops! My bad, I thought this was already set with edit access. All set now!

I *did* try and installable trigger, but was not able to get it to run with that, either.

Comment: Hi ! What are you exactly trying to achieve? If you could show a desired vs actual output to clarify what you want to achieve with your script it could be helpful. Also, I have realised that in your code when you call ```editTimestamp``` you are not passing it the ```sheet``` and therefore the variable ```sheet``` in that function is undefined and the script will fail to run. Either pass it as a paramter or create a new sheet varaible on ```editTimestamp```.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve with ```masterSheet.exec(name)``` ? That line of code will also return an error as the parameter you have passed ```masterSheet``` is simply a String.

Comment: I've added an example to  "1-Cover Sheet", highlighting in green what the info pulled from "W02" sheet should look like.
As for the editTimestamp and masterSheet.exec questions - both of these scripts have worked as single scripts. It seems like editTimestamp chooses which sheets to *not* apply to instead.  This section doesn't cut it? const sheet = range.getSheet();
masterSheet.exec I also wasn't clear about myself, but it was suggested to me here in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959210/sheets-filter-script-across-multiple-tabs-displaying-blank-rows-on-master-sheet

Comment: So you basically want to get and search all the marked green data from ```W02``` when you run the function and then update the timestamp cell of every sheet when an edit in that sheet is done right?

Comment: I ended up making them separate scripts, and running with assigned buttons and installed triggers, but yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your original script so that it doesn't run without any errors and so that both functions work accordingly. To sum up these are the changed I did to get your funcion to work successfully:

- Passed the `sheet` variable to `editTimestamp` as you were using it without passing it as a function argument (and thus it was returning a no reference error).
- In `updateMasterSheetRow` changed `masterSheet` to `masterSheetName` as this is the string you want to be checking and you already had defined this varaible in the function.
- Checked if the sheet matched with the masterSheet name instead of using regex [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) as it was of easier implementation and less prone to regular expression errors.
- Changed the `formula.cell` as this does not exist and set it to the right cell you want to set the formula to instead.

I have tested `editTimestamp` and it worked perfectly. However, `updateMasterSheetRow` worked but did not achieve your purpose as you will need to edit your `formulaText` to pull the right information from whichever sheet you want (currently it simply pulls empty information from the master sheet at the end of the sheet `B224:U225`).

Below is your script with the modifications I implemented to solve your issues:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const masterSheet = "1-Cover Sheet";
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const name = sheet.getName();
  const currentDate = new Date();
  
  // pass sheet to editTimestamp as a parameter
  editTimestamp(e, range, sheet);
  updateMasterSheetRows(e);
}

// receive the modified sheet
function editTimestamp(e, range,sheet) {

  var startRow = 1;
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if(col === 7 && row === 3 && sheet.getRange(1,14).getValue() == "" && 
     sheet.getName() != "4-Transfer Walkthru" && 
     sheet.getName() != "1-Cover Sheet" && 
     sheet.getName() != "2-Inventory" && 
     sheet.getName() != "3-Template"){
          Logger.log("1");
         sheet.getRange(1,14).setValue(currentDate);
       }
  
  else if(row >= startRow && 
     sheet.getName() != "4-Transfer Walkthru" && 
     sheet.getName() != "1-Cover Sheet" && 
     sheet.getName() != "2-Inventory" && 
     sheet.getName() != "3-Template"){
    
    sheet.getRange(2,14).setValue(currentDate);
       
  }  

  
  }


function updateMasterSheetRows(e) { 
  const masterSheetName = "1-Cover Sheet";
  const dataLocation = "B224:U225";

  const formulas = [
    {
      location: "B4",
      code: "is not null",
    },
    ];
  

  const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  

  let dataRangeParts = [];
  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    const name = sheet.getSheetName();

  // check that the sheet is not the same as the master sheet
    if(masterSheetName!=name){continue}

    dataRangeParts.push(`'${name}'!${dataLocation}`);
  }
  const dataRange = dataRangeParts.join(";");
    
  for (const formula of formulas) {

    const query = `SELECT * WHERE Col1 ${formula.code}`;
    const formulaText = `IFERROR(QUERY({${dataRange}},"${query}"),{"","",""})`;
    
    // change it so that the right cell is modified onEdit
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(masterSheetName).getRange(formula.location);
    cell.setFormula(formulaText);
  }
}
```